# A simple regex, extract what is between "/d/" and "/"

Tags: regex

I need to extract the xxxx in the following string in a url:

```
{anything}/d/xxxx/{anything}
```

That is, get whatever is between "/d/" and the first "/" after that, and forget the rest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't noticed what language you are using.

`.+\/d\/([^\/]+).+`

will do it and have the searched part in $1 (in perl)

Answer (score 3):

```
/d/(.*?)/
```

Will give you a capture group containing what you want.

[Regular Expression Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) is a decent place to start, otherwise get a tool such as [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) and have a play around!  It'll give you a plain text interpretation of the what your regular expression means.

Here's a tutorial to go along with Expresso: [The 30 Minute Regex Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/regextutorial.aspx).

Comment: This will not work if there can be multiple `/` characters following the `/d/` as it will capture beyond the first.

Comment: what @eldarerathis said. you can however simply change the `*` quantifier into its lazy version `*?`. then it'll work.

Comment: @eldarerathis: Good point, updated (as per @mhyfritz's comment).

Answer (score 1):

As for the question - I'm not really sure, but I've got this site bookmarked. It's a pretty good [Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

Hope this helps!